# Tikz: Rotating a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the below code I place a circle on an inclined plane.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\iangle{atan(4/5)}
\coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (A) at (5, 4);
\draw (O)--coordinate[pos=0.5] (mid) (A);

\begin{scope}[rotate=\iangle]
    \draw[fill=yellow] (mid) circle [radius=1cm, yshift=1cm];
\end{scope}    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
Even though this is as simple as it gets, is there an even more straightforward method, perhaps without `scope`? I ask because had the shape been, say, a square, I could do it just by rotating the shape and shifting.

Further; why `node` doesn't give the same result in the below code:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\iangle{atan(4/5)}
\coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (A) at (5, 4);
\draw (O)--coordinate[pos=0.5] (mid) (A);

\begin{scope}[rotate=\iangle]
    %\draw[fill=yellow] (mid) circle [radius=1cm, yshift=1cm];
    \node[draw, circle, minimum size=2cm,  yshift=1cm] at (mid) {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\iangle{atan(4/5)}
\coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (A) at (5, 4);
\draw (O)--coordinate (mid) (A);
%
    \node[draw, circle, minimum size=2cm, rotate=\iangle, yshift=1cm] at (mid) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

is what you looking for :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see why your solution works, but I do not see why the second option in my question does not. (`node` inside `scope`.)

Comment: @blackened, because `scope` not rotate node shape. for rotate it you need to move `rotate` to shape's options. For illustration, test `\begin{scope}[rotate=\iangle]
    \node (circle) [draw, circle, minimum size=2cm,  yshift=1cm] at (mid) {};
    \draw[fill=yellow] (circle.south) circle (1mm);
\end{scope}` and compare with `\node (circle) [draw, circle, minimum size=2cm, rotate=\iangle, yshift=1cm] at (mid) {};
    \draw[fill=yellow] (circle.south) circle (1mm);`.

Answer (score 3):

If there is no content (eg. text) that should be rotated, you can use a calculated `border anchor` to position the circle node. Then there is no need to know the size of this node.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (5,4);
\draw 
  let \p1=(O), \p2=(A),
      \n1={atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)},
      \n2={ifthenelse(abs(\n1)<=90,\n1-90,\n1+90}
  in  (O)--(A)
  node[pos=.5,draw,fill=yellow,minimum width=2cm,circle,anchor={\n2},outer sep=0pt]{}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Transformations in scopes do not apply to nodes automatically. But you can enable this transformations for shapes too: add `transform shape` to the `scope` options.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\iangle{atan(4/5)}
\coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
\coordinate (A) at (5, 4);
\draw (O)--coordinate[pos=0.5] (mid) (A);

\begin{scope}[rotate=\iangle,transform shape]
    \node[draw, circle, minimum size=2cm,yshift=1cm] at (mid) {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `atan2(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)` instead of `atan((\y2-\y1)/(\x2-\x1))`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Done, but what is the problem with `atan`?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Ok, division by `0` if I use `(0,4)` for `A`.

Comment: Yes. My example was bad... ;-)

Comment: But it helped me to understand the problem ;-)